# What does "@(#)<filename>" signify in comments?

Tags: c, version-control, comments

I'm looking at the source code for the venerable Unix game [Rogue](http://rogue.rogueforge.net/rogue-5-4/), and I've noticed that the comments at the head of each file contain a line in this format:

```
@(#)init.c   4.31 (Berkeley) 02/05/99
```

I've never seen the "@(#)" notation before, and I haven't been able to find an explanation of it anywhere. Could anyone tell me what this signifies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally, I figured this out immediately after posting my question when I stumbled upon a reference to an old version control system called [Source Code Control System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Code_Control_System). The mysterious comment is an "sccsid" string. From Wikipedia:

> After compilation, this string can be found in binary and object files by looking for the pattern "@(#)" and can be used determine which source code files were used during compilation.

Comment: I use `@(#)$Id$` to embed version strings in my code.  Both the `what` command (from SCCS) and the `ident` command (from RCS, which supports the `$Id$` style keywords) can find the version information.

Comment: Note that SCCS is a part of POSIX: [`admin`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/admin.html)
[`delta`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/delta.html)
[`get`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/get.html)
[`prs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/prs.html)
[`rmdel`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rmdel.html)
[`sact`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sact.html)
_[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ [`sccs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sccs.html)
[`unget`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/unget.html)
[`val`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/val.html)
[`what`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/what.html).  GNU provides [CSSC](https://gnu.org/software/cssc/) as its implementation of SCCS.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler CSSC is quite shitty though, for a more maintained version of SCCS, use [Schily SCCS](http://sccs.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @FUZxxl: I hadn't come across Schily SCCS.  Since it is based on the original SCCS (as open-sourced by OpenSolaris), it immediately has attractions to me.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the Source Code Control System: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Code_Control_System